# Mac OS X how to verify particular packages are installed

Tags: shell-script, command-line, osx, package-management

In a BASH script I need to check if `gcc, g++, cpp, make, libpng devel, zlib devel, git, Java` (including devel files), `ant` and `pkg-config` are available on Mac OS X and if not, I need to prompt user to install them.

This is easy task on Linux as it has package management tools, but I have no idea how to do this in Mac OS X shell. E.g. on openSUSE I can use `rpm -q` and `zypper in`, od Debian-based distros `dpkg-query` and `apt-get install`. But how to do it on a Mac?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple's package management system is often subject to criticism. The utility `pkgutil` can be used to list and query the package receipts.

List all the packages installed with Apple's installer

```
     pkgutil --pkgs
```

Regex for a package id

```
    pkgutil --pkgs=.\+Xcode.\+
```

List all the files in a package id

```
    pkgutil --only-files --files com.apple.pkg.update.devtools.3.2.6.XcodeUpdate
```

Then again you could use `lsbom` and read the bom files in /var/db/receipts

Users also install other package management systems such as MacPorts, fink, or Homebrew. Or compile their own in whatever prefix. `pkgutil` will not list packages installed by these methods.

If your target operating system is OS X10.9 or OS X 10.10 then

```
    gcc --version
```

Either the command will output the gcc version or you will be prompted to install the XCode command line tools. `gcc, g++, cpp, make, and git` will be installed along with other tools. The Java package is offered from Oracle. You could test with `java --version` though you'll need to familiarize yourself with Apple's frameworks, plugins, and bundles to search for header files. `pkgutil` would be a good candidate for this process.

The other packages you mentioned could possibly be compiled with in a shell script or compiled and put into an Apple installer package then installed via a shell script. There isn't an easy method.

Comment: So that I can not rely on `pkgutil` when querying for installed packages? I'd like to check on as basic OS X as possible without relying on 3rd party tools like MacPorts, Flink or Homebrew if some packages are installed and if not, install them...

Answer (score 3):

if this package has a binary that can be found, you can do -

```
package_name=<packge-name>
t=`which $package_name`
[ -z "$t" ] && echo "the $package_name isn't installed!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is `system_profiler`:

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
```

The output of the above command will look similar to a `yum info`
There are plenty of other options to throw at this utility.  `man system_profiler` should get you on the right track.  This [blog entry](http://macstuff.beachdogs.org/blog/?p=21) will provide you with a little more information.

Comment: As far as I understand this tool from its man, it seems I can only verify if particular software is installed, which is important step, just only the first step. Is there something like zypper or apt-get for Mac?

Comment: Sadly the man page doesn't outline all of the options in `system_profiler`.  If you check out the blog I linked you might get a little more info.

Comment: OK, thank You for details. But still I see only possibilities for querying...

Comment: @h3rrmiller It appears that as of 2019-01-13 the link to blog entry does not seem to work, although I found useful info via this link http://macstuff.beachdogs.org/blog/?s=system+profiler&submit=Search